# Eloquent 5.4 - HasMany Object Mass Update Timestamps

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

really need your help here. ( I don't know what I want is possible on Eloquent )

Lets pretend this Relationship: **One user can have many Childs**

**Note: Ignore problems in the code, this is just an example.**

Now lets add some code into it.

```
// Return HasMany Object Instance from Eloquent.
$hasMany = $user->childs()

// Perform Mass Update.
$hasMany->update(['born_at' => Carbon::now])
```

So far nothing wrong with it, the first line returns an **HasMany Object** ( [Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html) )

The problem is that Mass Updating touches my Model's timestamps ( **created_at, updated_at** ) and specially for this update I don't want it to do that.

Disabling it on the Model is not an option for me I do use the timestamp touch normally but I don't want to use in this case.

Neither I want to iterate over the Collection ( **$user->child**s ) because I have many rows to update and its an **overhead to generate one query for each Model to update.**

**What I expect for an answer to this question:** Simple, I just want an way to turn off the timestamps to do the mass updating or something like that.

( Normally on a single Model you can disable it like this: **$model->timestamps = false**, but this will not work here because **hasMany instance** does not have this attribute. )

Answer (score 0):

You could set the property default of the model to false. So in you're model class you will have:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

But this will always disable the timestamps until je use:

```
$model->timestamps = true;
```

Comment: This is an possible solution but I only need to disable timestamps in the specific operation. I would need to enable timestamps for the whole application everytime I wanted to touch the Model timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone finds this through Google:

One possible solution is to Fallback to the base QueryBuilder:

```
(new Child)
    ->newQuery()
    ->toBase()
    ->where('parent_id', $model->id)
    ->update([
        'born_at' => Carbon::now,
    ]);
```

Of course, one could just use here something like DB::table(...)...